# Excel VBA: Getting error or success with Omniture Adobe Report Builder

Tags: excel, vba, adobe-analytics

I'm pretty new to VBA, so please pardon silly questions.
I'm making an automated excel file with many Report Builder queries; it will be part of a bigger automation.
I need it to (auto) check if the refresh procedure was successfully completed, but I'm not able to:
-get the success object in any form;
-get ANY information on errors it may raise.
The module with the refresh procedure works, I copied it from Greg-J's answer to this question:
[Automating Omniture Report Builder Refresh in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28597394/automating-omniture-report-builder-refresh-in-excel-vba)

```
Sub Refresh()
Debug.Print ("refresh started")

'chiamata di refresh del plugIn di Abode Report Builder
Dim addIn As COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object
    Dim success As String
    Set addIn = Application.COMAddIns("ReportBuilderAddIn.Connect")
    Set automationObject = addIn.Object
    success = automationObject.RefreshAllRequests(ActiveWorkbook)

    'ErrorHandler
    Dim Msg
    ' If an error occurs, construct an error message
    On Error Resume Next    ' Defer error handling.
    Err.Clear
    Err.Raise 513    ' Generate an "Overflow" error.
    ' Check for error, then show message.
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
                & Err.source & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If

    Debug.Print (success)

Worksheets("Weekly SkySport- Chiamate Adobe").Range("F1").Value = "success"
Worksheets("Weekly SkySport- Chiamate Adobe").Range("D1").Value = Date

Debug.Print ("refresh completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For us to help you, you will have to provide what you have tried so far (in this case your code). Screen prints are very useful. Might be worth reading up on [How to as a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks. Edited reporting the module's code